# ng-repeat and the mouseover event

Tags: mouseover, angularjs-ng-repeat

this seems like a scope problem, but i am not sure.  my goal is to highlight a single row in a table.  that implies that any previously highlighted row is returned to an unhighlighted state.  the rows are created with the ng-repeat directive, like this:

```
<div id="myFedContents" style="height:320px" ng-controller="Controller2" class="scroller">
    <table border="0" class="span12 table table-condensed" style="margin-left:0px" id="tblData">
        <thead>
            <tr><th>Year</th><th>Name</th><th>Useful Flag</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="allRows">
            <tr ng-repeat="item in itemlist | filter:thisText" ng-style="myStyle">            <td class="span1" valign="top"><a tabindex="-1" href="#">{{item.year}}</a></td>
                <td id="{{item.id}}">                                   <a tabindex="-1" href="#" ng-click="myStyle={'background-color':'#cccccc'};">{{item.name}}</a>
                </td>                                     <td>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-small btn-link">{{item.usefulflag}</a> 
                </td>                                 </tr>                             
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

i have code in a .js file that looks like this:

```
$("tr").mouseenter(function(){
    alert("mouseenter");
});
```

the row in the table header reacts with the alert, but there is no reaction from the rows created by ng-repeat.  how do i correct?

Answer (score 3):

You can actually achieve this effect by using an ng-class in conjuction with ng-mouseenter and ng-mouseleave like so:

```
<div id="myFedContents" style="height:320px" ng-controller="Controller2" class="scroller">
  <table border="0" class="span12 table table-condensed" style="margin-left:0px" id="tblData">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Useful Flag</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="allRows">
      <tr ng-repeat="item in itemlist | filter:thisText" ng-style="myStyle" ng-class="highlightclass" ng-mouseenter="highlightclass='highlight'" ng-mouseleave="highlightclass=''">
        <td class="span1" valign="top"><a tabindex="-1" href="#">{{item.year}}</a>
        </td>
        <td id="{{item.id}}"> <a tabindex="-1" href="#" ng-click="myStyle={'background-color':'#cccccc'};">{{item.name}}</a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-small btn-link">{{item.usefulflag}</a> 
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

In this case you don't need the jquery syntax. If you haven't already you should also read https://stackoverflow.com/a/15012542/281335.